# Increment using 2 digit number

Tags: powershell

I have the following to code to append incremental number to the beggining of each filename. How can I make it start with 01 instead of 1.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\test"

$i = 1
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newname = "$i" + $file
    Rename-Item $($file.FullName) $newname
    $i++
}
```

Comment: `$i.ToString('00')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways to do this, I would use the -f (format) operator.

Here's how I'd write it in a pipeline:

```
 Get-ChildItem "C:\test" | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i=1 } { 
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("{0:D2}{1}" -f ($i++, $_.Name)) 
    }
```

P.S. I frequently forget but it's even possible to eliminate the ForEach-Object using a delay-bind ScriptBlock.   This comes in particularly handy for Rename-Item:

```
$i = 1 
Get-ChildItem "C:\test" | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0:D2}{1}" -f ($i++, $_.Name)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That gave me the last piece I needed for my program. I did have to add C:\test after the Rename-Item because it tried to save it in the current directory instead of the directory the file was in.